# How to draw four-bar linkage with center of mass?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, engineering

[image]

How can I draw a four-bar linkage with all the hinges and beams, like this in the picture??

I'm just starting out with LaTex ... This is what I made :

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\point{a}{0}{0};
\point{first}{-1}{0};
\notation{1}{first}{A};
\support{1}{a};
\hinge{1}{a};

\point{d}{0.9}{0};
\point{first}{0.8}{0.1};
\notation{1}{first}{D};
\beam{4}{a}{d};
\support{1}{d};
\hinge{1}{d};

\point{b}{-1.6485}{4.2945};
\point{first}{-1.6485}{4.2945};
\notation{1}{first}{B};
\hinge{1}{b};
\beam{4}{b}{a};


\point{c}{3.7241}{2.3905};
\point{first}{3.7241}{2.3905};
\notation{1}{first}{C};
\hinge{1}{c};
\beam{4}{b}{c};
\beam{4}{c}{d};


\draw [->] (0,0) -- (10,0) node [above left]  {$\operatorname{X} $};
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,10) node [below right] {$\operatorname{Y} $};

\coordinate (x) at (0.3,0);
\coordinate (y) at (0,0.3);

\coordinate (w) at (2,0);
\coordinate (k) at (-0.4,4.2945);

\draw pic[draw, "$\theta_2$", ->, angle eccentricity=1.3,angle radius = 
0.6cm] {angle = x--a--b}; 
\draw pic[draw, "$\theta_4$", ->, angle eccentricity=1.3,angle radius = 1cm] 
{angle = w--d--c};
\draw pic[draw, "$\theta_3$", ->, angle eccentricity=1.3,angle radius = 1cm] 
 {angle = k--b--a};

\draw (-1.6485,4.2945) -- (-0.5,4.2945);
\draw [dash dot] (-1.6485,4.2945) -- (.9,0);

% I wanna make the center of mass and place it where a want...


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the result :
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) This is not a "do it for me" site. We are glad to help but you should first post what you have tried so far and ask specific questions for the bits you are stuck with.

Comment: Agreeing 100% with @campa it is important to know what are your knowledges on PStricks, Asymptote, Metapost, TikZ-PGF, ecc.

Answer (score 2):

`Asymptote` version:

```
// "linkage.asy"
//    run 
//  asy linkage.asy
//    to get a standalone image "linkage.pdf"
//
settings.tex="pdflatex";
import graph;
import geometry;
size(8cm);
import fontsize;defaultpen(fontsize(8pt));
texpreamble("\usepackage{lmodern}"+"\usepackage{amsmath}"+"\usepackage{amsfonts}"+"\usepackage{amssymb}");

pen linePen=darkblue+1bp;
pen dashPen=orange+0.7bp+linetype(new real[]{5,5})+linecap(0); //squarecap =linecap(0)
pen supPen=gray(0.36)+0.3bp;

arrowbar arrs=Arrows(SimpleHead,size=3);

real w=24, h=15, r=5, R=100;
real d=385;
real psi0=80, psi =50;
real AB=400;
real c=257;

pair A0=(180,130);
pair B0=A0+d;
pair B1=rotate(psi0,B0)*(B0+c);
pair B2=rotate(psi,B0)*B1;
pair A1=A0+R*unit(B1-A0);
pair A2=A0+R*unit(A0-B2);

void pivot(pair sh, pen fillPen=white, pen edgePen=linePen, pen basePen=linePen+2*bp+extendcap){
  transform tr=shift(sh);
  pair C=(0,h);
  guide g=(w/2,0)--(w/2,h)--arc(C,w/2,0,180)--(-w/2,0)--cycle;
  filldraw(tr*g^^tr*circle(C,r),fillPen,edgePen);
  pair A=tr*(-20,0);
  pair B=tr*( 20,0);
  int n=10;
  real di=(B.x-A.x)/n;
  for(int i=0;i<n+1;++i) xtick(z=A+(i*di,0),dir=plain.SSW,size=ticksize,p=basePen+0.4*bp);
  draw(A--B,basePen);
}

guide gsup=(0,0)--(50,0);

draw(A0--B1--B0,linePen);
draw(A2--B2--B0,linePen);
draw(circle(A0,R),dashPen);
draw(arc(B0,B1,B2),dashPen);
draw(shift(A0+20)*gsup,supPen);
draw(shift(B0+20)*gsup,supPen);
pivot(A0-(0,h));
pivot(B0-(0,h));

label("$A_0$",A0,2*plain.W);
label("$B_0$",B0,2*plain.W);
dot("$A_1$",A1,plain.ESE,UnFill);
dot("$A_2$",A2,plain.SW,UnFill);
dot("$B_1$",B1,plain.NE,UnFill);
dot("$B_2$",B2,plain.NW,UnFill);

markangle(Label("$\theta_0$",Relative(0.5)),n=1,radius=-18,B1,A0,B0,p=linePen+0.3bp,arrs);
markangle(Label("$\theta$",Relative(0.5)),n=1,radius=-46,B2,A0,B1,p=linePen+0.3bp,arrs);
markangle(Label("$\psi_0$",Relative(0.5)),n=1,radius=-10,B1,B0,B0+plain.E,p=linePen+0.3bp,arrs);
markangle(Label("$\psi$",Relative(0.5)),n=1,radius=-14,B2,B0,B1,p=linePen+0.3bp,arrs);

label("$a$",(A0+A2)/2,plain.SE);
label("$b$",A1*(1-0.6)+B1*0.6,plain.N);
label("$c$",(B0+B1)/2,plain.SE);
label("$d=A_0B_0$",(A0+R+B0)/2);
shipout(bbox(Fill(paleyellow)));
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for `xtick`.

Comment: oh thanks a lot man!! I was not aware of Asymptote. I used tikzpicture and the stanli package.